# django-watson does not work properly

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using `django-watson` as a full text search engine but it seems that it cannot do 'real full text search'.

My model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('author'))
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(_('content'))
```

Registration:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

from watson import search as watson


class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'articles'

    def ready(self):
        watson.register(self.get_model('Article'), fields=(
            'title', 'content'), store=('title', 'content'))
```

And some set-up code:

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    Article(
        author=self.user,
        title='title%s' % i,
        content='content%s' % i,
    ).save()
```

Now if I perform:

```
len(watson.search('cont'))
```

It will return 19, which is the correct answer. **But if I perform**:

```
len(watson.search('1'))
```

It will return 0 incorrectly.

I've tried several test cases and it seems that **only items starting with keyword will be found**. How to solve it ?

I'm using:

- python 3.5.1
- django 1.9.7
- django-watson 1.2.1 (latest)
- postgresql 9.4

Thanks.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that by adding the `store`parameter when registering the model, you're basically telling watson these are additional fields (see https://github.com/etianen/django-watson/wiki/Registering-models#including-additional-fields-in-the-search-results)? Could this have been confusing watson?

Comment: @LaundroMat Could u solve ur issue?